# Investment methods for a US non-resident alien, living in the US for the next 2-5 years only

Tags: ira, retirement, investing, non-resident

If an employer does not offer a 401k plan, what options do I have to invest in stocks, bonds, ETFs, etc.?

Would a Roth account be a viable option considering I will probably be in the US for 2-5 more years?

Should I just open a brokerage account with a low cost firm (Schwab, Scottstrade, etc.) and invest my after tax dollars?

Comment: Where are you otherwise a citizen/resident?

Comment: citizen of Egypt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said, yes you can open a brokerage account. They will ask you for some identifying information and you will have to have a valid visa. You can also contribute to a Roth IRA.

I think the more important questions you should be asking are:

- How does my home country treat retirement accounts in US?
- Is the investment in a US Traditional IRA treated as tax deferred as
     well?
- Is the Roth IRA treated as tax-free?
- What if you leave the US and need the money before retirement?

I think it's important to come up with a long term plan. It might be better to just open a regular account and invest. Again all of it depends on how your home country treats income from the US.

**EDIT:** You will pay an early [withdrawal penalty](http://www.fool.com/money/allaboutiras/allaboutiras07.htm) from a Roth IRA unless otherwise stated in the [US tax treaty with Egypt](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/egypt.pdf).

Some resources that might be helpful:

[U.S. Taxation of Foreign Investors](http://www.lehmantaxlaw.com/seminar/USTAX_seminar_online.pdf)

[Taxation of Foreign Nationals by the United States](http://www.deloitte.com/assets/Dcom-Austria/Local%20Assets/Documents/GlobalEmployerServices_Taxation%20of%20Foreign%20Nationals.pdf)

Comment: I don't know of any enforced laws at my home country regarding retirement and investment accounts. Emphasis on "enforced". If i contribute to a Roth IRA with after tax money, can I withdraw all the money in the account and close it if i leave the US? do you know what kind of penalties would apply then, if any?

Comment: @ZeroSubnet I have updated my answer.

Comment: @KirillFuchs: the penalty would only be on the earnings